# How to calculate the vector direction to point , so the object will move to

Tags: movement, vector

i like to be able to calculate the vector values from object A to destination position.
For Example in this image object A to destination B .
What will be the x/y positions all the way until it reach distention B.
where the x,y origin is in bottom left side 
[image]

Comment: Isn't a subtraction of A from B sufficient (`Diff = B - A`)? Also, the amount of positions between A and B is infinite. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: to calculate the movement from A to B

Comment: That's not enough information to give an answer... If you want to move 10% of the distance just scale the vector by 10%. I feel like this question lacks research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the the vector from 'A' to 'B' thats 'C = TargetPos - StartPos = B - A', no matter how they are orientated.

If you want a function to return a position on this line between, that's 'pos(x) = StartPos + (TargetPos - StartPos) * x = A + C * x',  where either x is a number between 0 ( lower you would have a point further away from B) or 1 (higher means you went through B and got further).

Most of the time your 'C' gets normalized, so still points in the same direction, but has 'length = 1', so `C_n = C / Length of C`.
. In that case x should be between 0 and 'Lenght of C'.